# What are the key personality traits and topics to discuss about when being introduced to senior management?

Tags: career

One of the keys to success is to start with the right foot when being introduced to senior management. How one would focus such presentation and what are the key aspects to be mentioned?

I do not want to talk about my personal life in a professional environment nor have had yet any major success in my career (which would be the logical items to cover on such intro) so I'm not sure on how to approach it. What would senior managers like to know from new joiners?

In this specific case, I'm going to have a presentation speech at my PMI Toastmasters club, a worldwide club devoted to improve people's communication skills with learning by doing.

Comment: Not a question about project management.

Comment: I needed to ask project managers and I could not think of a better place.

Comment: Please respect the advertised scope.  See [help]

Comment: Tried to rephrase it to make it a bit more Q&A, but still I don't see it a fit for PMSE. Maybe... _maybe_... at workplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It obviously depends on the environment, but I think you might be under a false assumption when you say:

> I do not want to talk about my personal life in a professional environment.

The purpose of the Icebreaker Toastmasters speech is just as the name implies - to break the ice. It can be about anything. I myself gave my speech (which, as well, was hosted in the company to which I was at the time employed) about pets, the clarinet, and my favourite Latin phrase. It seemed to go over well enough.

Of course, like I said, it depends on the environment. The first thing you should do is ask the President of the Toastmasters group just how strongly tied to your profession the Toastmasters group (and your speech) are expected to be. That will be a better guide than anything anyone here could tell you. If you don't know who your Toastmasters President is (it changes annually, if I recall correctly), just ask the other members.

Comment: I just want the speech to be interesting for them and yet professional enough. If I tell them about my education, my hobbies, I don't see those facts to be useful to them in any way. Actually, thanks for your answer, I am thinking that since they are all from the construction industry, I can talk abt how software dev project management differs and why I want to be a part of it. It is still going to be a good thing for them to learn. I worked as a pm in a web dev company, I can talk about this process!

Comment: @Stella There you go, then. Though I *would* still recommend asking what sort of tone to set your speech to. No reason not to gain more information to prepare. Good luck.

Comment: I worked as a technical project coordinator, I will talk abt my previous work experience. Yeah, I will still talk to a president or get a mentor hopefully. This club is semi-professional + I still want them to know what I have been working on networking purposes. My main goal is to learn how to be diplomatic and business-like from those club meetings + prepare for future interviews.